# Which class should be used to create TLS connection in java. Socket class or SSLSocket class?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, openfire, sslsocketfactory

I am trying to create a simple java client to connect to port 5223 of a presence server(Openfire). The presence server docs tell me that this port supports only secure TLS connections.

So I try to connect to the 5223 port using the below code.

```
SSLSocketFactory factory=(SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket socket= (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket("host",5223);
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
BufferedWriter writer =new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8"));
writer.write("some data");
writer.flush();
char r0[]= new char[600];
reader.read(r0);
System.out.println(r0);
```

This worked fine and i could see that(in wireshark) the data i sent as well as the responce I received were encrypted.

Next I tried the below code

```
Socket socket=new Socket("host", 5223);
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
BufferedWriter writer =new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8"));
writer.write("some data");
writer.flush();
char r0[]= new char[600];
reader.read(r0);
System.out.println(r0);
```

Surpisingly(for me) this too works. The only issue being i got some 7 byte unexpected response in the begining. But when i skipped that response, all other responses seem to work fine and I even saw that the data is encrypted(using wireshark).

I am confused. If the Socket class itself is able to provide the secured communication then why should we user the SSLSocket class.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

- Clearly the documentation of the server is wrong in saying it only supports TLS via that port, and
- Clearly it is using the STARTTLS feature by which you start with a plaintext connection and can upgrade it to TLS by issuing the STARTTLS command.

Comment: Thaks for the reply. But I hav not sent any start tls command and the data still seems to be encrypted. How is this possible.